# Google Analytics Looses UTM campaign, source for paid ad traffic ; Hits show as-if they have no Landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

We are seeing consistent problems with a Universal Analytics (ga). with some custom dimensions

it is written here in ERB, a Ruby-like syntax for generating the custom dimensions

```
<% if tracker = Spree::Tracker.current %>
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', '<%= tracker.analytics_id %>', 'auto');
    var ga_pageview_dimensions = {'dimension2': '<%= purchaser_status(@order) %>'};
    <% if spree_current_user %>
    ga_pageview_dimensions.dimension1 = '<%= spree_current_user.analytics_id %>';
    <% end %>
    <% if @attach_marionette_view && @page %>
    ga_pageview_dimensions.dimension3 = '<%= @page.thumbprint %>';
    <% end %>

    <% if session[:traffic_split_destination] %>
    ga_pageview_dimensions.dimension4 = '<%= session[:traffic_split_destination] %>';
    <% end %>

    ga('send', 'pageview', ga_pageview_dimensions);

  </script>
<% end %>
```

This produces an HTML output like:

```
 <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    var ga_pageview_dimensions = {'dimension2': 'new'};
    ga_pageview_dimensions.dimension3 = 'b093e-f6a22-68174-c14a6-ce42d-6fba8-76777-5be06-f8854-909b1-c4251-30203';


    ga('send', 'pageview', ga_pageview_dimensions);

  </script>
```

This code is placed just before the closing  tag,

On a particular day (let's say yesterday, Nov 1), Paid Google advertising traffic produces traffic that appears with a referral of :

tpc.googlesyndication.com / referral

We had 138 sessions for this source / medium. (the data from all screenshots is only date range Nov1-Nov1)

However what doesn't make sense is that this traffic should have been correctly tagged with inbound utm_campaign and utm_source. This traffic is showing 
"(not set)" for all 138 sessions, and a medium of "referral" for all 138 sessions (this appears to be wrong, since we believe all of this traffic is Paid ad traffic, and all of it should have correctly set utm values here)

[image]

[image]

As well, I am seeing two more mysteries  regarding Landing pages. Many have landing page "(not set)" which makes no sense since a visitor must have a landing page. This group almost always has an average session duration < 1 section, so I surmise that no landing page is being captured for bouncers

However, we also see about 25% of people with a landing page of /cart, which does not make sense since we have no inbound links to /cart and it would be impossible to start on that page
[image]

This affects multiple sources of ad-traffic where we believe we should be seeing UTM information but aren't any. All of this traffic comes in as-if it were "referral" traffic but we believe that it is in fact paid search traffic.

I should also mention that GTM is installed, just after the opening , which we use only for dataLayer pushes of our addToCart action & our completed order transaction. GTM is hooked into our GA install via a GTM tag that pushes the e-commerce event into GA for tracking. In no other way are GTM and GA connected as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things going on here that could be related but may not be.

Q1. Why is that referrer showing up?
A1. That referrer is from Google's Adsense network that you will likely have enabled one way or another either directly from your paid search advertising or if you're doing any other advertising on Google.  It will only be overwritten if the utm_source parameter is present in the URL as a minimum.

Process for debugging is:

1. Check that auto-tagging is enabled in your Adwords account
2. Check the syntax of the destination url to make sure it is what you expect

Q2. Why do you have (not set) for a landing page.
A2. First let's cover what a landing page is.  GA defines it as being the starting page of a session where a event type of pageview is set.  As such it is possible for this to have '(not set)' or odd values if:

1. The events sent are not of pageview type for some reason, not uncommon for purchase flows or if filters are applied to a View
2. The session gets re-established somehow - this can happen if a new campaign is set part-way through a flow

Without digging into your account via admin access this is as much as I can help.  I hope this gives you something to work with but let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Yes we are after two competing theories, in fact just as your answer suggests: (1) no UTM is sent correctly, thus causing 'referrer' inaccurately, and (2) session get re-established somewhere. Your observations are indeed in line with the hypotheses we are chasing down.